# Suggestions for Buy/Sell signals overlaid on TradingChart

Tags: finance, charts

To visually evaluate a backtester, I would like to overlay "buy" and "sell" signals on `TradingChart`, while preserving the interactive functionality of `TradingChart` (hence no `GraphicsColumn`), using different colors of `GridLines` on a `DateListPlot` would have been a solution, but this doesn't have the necessary interactivity of `TradingChart`.

[image]

Comment: Is this a feature request or a question on how to implement this?  If it is a feature request, please contact Wolfram: http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/  Take a look at Scope -> Labeling in the documentation page of this function, it may be useful.

Comment: I didn't know about Labeling, this might work, I will try.

Comment: yeah I'm very happy with Labeling Events, thank you.

Comment: @JeromeIbanes please consider posting an answer then

Answer (score 2):

Wrap selected data points `Labeled` and wrap `TrandingChart` with `Legended`:

```
Legended[TradingChart[{{{2010, 10, 1}, {530.`, 530.62`, 523.`,   525.62`, 2225000}}, 
  {{2010, 10, 4}, {524.95`, 528.25`, 518.85`, 522.35`, 1940500}}, 
   Labeled[{{2010, 10, 5}, {528.38`, 540.`, 526.55`, 538.23`,  3507100}}, 
    Style["\[FreakedSmiley]", 30, Red], Below], 
  {{2010, 10, 6}, {539.26`, 539.95`, 529.94`, 534.35`, 2762300}}, 
   Labeled[{{2010, 10, 7}, {536.1`, 537.2`, 529.14`, 530.01`, 2395800}}, 
    Style["\[HappySmiley]", 30, Green], Above], 
  {{2010, 10, 8}, {532.77`, 537.6`, 527.62`, 536.35`, 2859200}}}], 
 Placed[Grid[{{Style["\[FreakedSmiley]", 30, Red], Style["SELL SIGNAL", 16,  Bold]}, 
 {Style["\[HappySmiley]", 30, Green], Style["BUY SIGNAL", 16,  Bold]}}], {.2, .85}]]
```

[image]